# Email from PHP has broken Subject header encoding

Tags: php, encoding, mime, email-headers

My PHP script sends email to users and when the email arrives to their mailboxes, the subject line (`$subject`) has characters like `a^£` added to the end of my subject text. This is obviously and encoding problem. The email message content itself is fine, just the subject line is broken.

I have searched all over but can’t find **how to encode my subject properly**.

This is my header. Notice that I’m using `Content-Type` with `charset=utf-8` and  `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`.

```
//set all necessary headers
$headers = "From: $sender_name<$from>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $sender_name<$from>\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender: $sender_name<$from>\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP4\n"; //mailer
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n"; //1 UrgentMessage, 3 Normal
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
$headers .= "Importance: 3\n";
$headers .= "Date: $date\n";
$headers .= "Delivered-to: $to\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $sender_name<$from>\n";
$headers .= "Envelope-from: $sender_name<$from>\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
```

Comment: Have you thought about using http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ this will save you loads of hassle.

Comment: In addition to the provided answers, note that according to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), you are supposed to separate multiple headers with CRLF (`\r\n`), not just LF (`\n`).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Update**   For a more practical and up-to-date answer, have a look at [Palec’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648245/53114).

---

The specified character encoding in *Content-Type* does only describe the character encoding of the message body but not the header. You need to use the [*encoded-word* syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-2) with either the [*quoted-printable* encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7) or the [Base64 encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.8):

```
encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

You can use [`imap_8bit`](http://php.net/imap_8bit) for the *quoted-printable* encoding and [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) for the Base64 encoding:

```
"Subject: =?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?="
"Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?".imap_8bit($subject)."?="
```

Comment: gumbo, I dont understand the difference between base64 or imap_8bit? When should I use one or other? would it be like this : $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=this is the subject'; or for I not need the '?=' where subject text goes?

Comment: @user535256: No, the actual subject needs to be encoded with one of the encodings. Which one you pick is your decision. *Quoted-printable* is quite more readable as most of the printable ASCII characters are retained; but it will take more space if your subjects are likely to contain a lot of non-ASCII characters as each byte will be replaced by one three byte sequence of `=xx`.

Comment: In the project I was working on there was a problem with characters from Russian language. Here is a code that had a not valid character in UTF8.

`Subject: =?utf-8?B?0LjQstGB0YLRg9C/0LjRgtC10LvRjNC90L7QtSDQsdGA0L7Q?=
 =?utf-8?B?vdC40YDQvtCy0LDQvdC40LUg0L3QvtC80LXRgNGMIDA0OC0xMzktMTMg?=
 =?utf-8?B?LSBBbWlnb3MgQXBhcnRtZW50IC0g0L/Qu9Cw0YLQtdC2INC/0LXRgNC1?=
 =?utf-8?B?0YfQuNGB0LvQtdC90LXQvA==?=`

Comment: Finally I fixed problem by putting each word into separate line of the message header:
`Subject: =?utf-8?B?0LjQstGB0YLRg9C/0LjRgtC10LvRjNC90L7QtQ==?=
 =?utf-8?B?INCx0YDQvtC90LjRgNC+0LLQsNC90LjQtQ==?=
 =?utf-8?B?INC90L7QvNC10YDRjA==?=
 =?utf-8?B?IDA1Mi0xMzktMTM=?=
 =?utf-8?B?IC0=?=
 =?utf-8?B?IEFtaWdvcw==?=
 =?utf-8?B?IEFwYXJ0bWVudA==?=
 =?utf-8?B?IC0=?=
 =?utf-8?B?INC/0LvQsNGC0LXQtg==?=
 =?utf-8?B?INC/0LXRgNC10YfQuNGB0LvQtdC90LXQvA==?=`

I hope this will be helpful for someone - I spend 8h on debugging and fixing that problem.

Comment: You can also use [quoted_printable_encode()](http://uk.php.net/function.quoted-printable-encode.php) which according to the doc, *is similar to `imap_8bit()`, except this one does not require the IMAP module to work*.

Comment: While the basic idea is OK, this method violates the RFC for longer inputs. It is specified that each encoded word (`=?…?…?…?=`) must be at most 75 chars long and lines containing encoded words must be at most 76 chars long (including the space at the beginning of a continuation line). It is necessary to encode the text into more words and fold the field so that it fits into the limits.

Comment: Note that because of [RFC6532](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6532) what you did originally should now work with email clients that implement it, however, the rfc is very recent (2012) so I guess very few clients implement it.

Answer (score 74):

## TL;DR

```
$preferences = ['input-charset' => 'UTF-8', 'output-charset' => 'UTF-8'];
$encoded_subject = iconv_mime_encode('Subject', $subject, $preferences);
$encoded_subject = substr($encoded_subject, strlen('Subject: '));
mail($to, $encoded_subject, $message, $headers);
```

or

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$encoded_subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, 'UTF-8', 'B', "\r\n", strlen('Subject: '));
mail($to, $encoded_subject, $message, $headers);
```

## Problem and solution

The `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers apply only to the body of your message. For headers, there is a mechanism for specifying their encoding specified in [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).

You should encode your `Subject` via [`iconv_mime_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-encode.php), which exists as of PHP 5:

```
$preferences = ["input-charset" => "UTF-8", "output-charset" => "UTF-8"];
$encoded_subject = iconv_mime_encode("Subject", $subject, $preferences);
```

<sup>Change `input-charset` to match the encoding of your string `$subject`. You should leave `output-charset` as `UTF-8`. Before PHP 5.4, use `array()` instead of `[]`.</sup>

Now `$encoded_subject` is (without trailing newline)

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VmVyeSBsb25nIHRleHQgY29udGFpbmluZyBzcGVjaWFsIGM=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?aGFyYWN0ZXJzIGxpa2UgxJvFocSNxZnFvsO9w6HDrcOpPD4/PSsqIHA=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?cm9kdWNlcyBzZXZlcmFsIGVuY29kZWQtd29yZHMsIHNwYW5uaW5nIG0=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?dWx0aXBsZSBsaW5lcw==?=
```

for `$subject` containing:

```
Very long text containing special characters like ěščřžýáíé<>?=+* produces several encoded-words, spanning multiple lines
```

## How does it work?

The `iconv_mime_encode()` function splits the text, encodes each piece separately into an [`<encoded-word>`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-2) token and [folds](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-11) the whitespace between them. Encoded word is `=?<charset>?<encoding>?<encoded-text>?=` where:

- `<encoding>` is either `B` (for [Base 64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.8) – see [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)) or `Q` (for [Quoted-printable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7) – see [`quoted_printable_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php)),
- `<encoded-text>` is string encoded with `<encoding>`, which has charset `<charset>` after being decoded.

You can decode `=?CP1250?B?QWhvaiwgc3bsdGU=?=` into UTF-8 string `Ahoj, světe` (`Hello, world` in Czech) via `iconv("CP1250", "UTF-8", base64_decode("QWhvaiwgc3bsdGU="))` or directly via `iconv_mime_decode("=?CP1250?B?QWhvaiwgc3bsdGU=?=", 0, "UTF-8")`.

Encoding into encoded words is more complicated, because the spec requires each encoded-word token to be at most 75 bytes long and each line containing any encoded-word token must be at most 76 bytes long (including blank at the start of a continuation line). **Don’t implement the encoding yourself. All you really need to know is that `iconv_mime_encode()` respects the spec.**

Interesting related reading is the Wikipedia article [Unicode and email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_email).

## Alternatives

A rudimentary option is to use only a restricted set of characters. ASCII is guaranteed to work. ISO Latin 1 (ISO-8859-1), as [user2250504 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20436399/2157640), will probably work too, because it is often used as fallback when no encoding is specified. But those character sets are very small and you’ll probably be unable to encode all the characters you’ll want. Moreover, the RFCs say nothing about whether Latin 1 should work or not.

You can also use [`mb_encode_mimeheader()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php), as [Paul Norman answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392582/2157640), but it’s easy to use it incorrectly.

1. You must use [`mb_internal_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) to set the mbstring functions’ internally used encoding. The `mb_*` functions expect input strings to be in this encoding. Beware: The second parameter of `mb_encode_mimeheader()` has nothing to do with the input string (despite what the manual says). It corresponds to the `<charset>` in the encoded word (see *How does it work?* above). The input string is recoded from the internal encoding to this one before being passed to the B or Q encoding.

   Setting internal encoding might not be needed since PHP 5.6, because the underlying [`mbstring.internal_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.internal-encoding) configuration option had been deprecated in favor of the [`default_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) option, which has been set to UTF-8 by default, since. Note that this is just a default and it may be inappropriate to rely on defaults in your code.
2. You must include the header name and colon in the input string. The RFC imposes a strong limit on line length and it must hold for the first line, too! An alternative is to fiddle with the fifth parameter (`$indent`; last one as of September 2015), but this is even less convenient.
3. The implementation might have bugs. Even if used correctly, you might get broken output. At least this is what many comments on the manual page say. I have not managed to find any problem, but I know implementation of encoded words is tricky. *If you find potential or actual bugs in `mb_encode_mimeheader()` or `iconv_mime_encode()`, please, let me know in the comments.*

There is also at least one upside to using `mb_encode_mimeheader()`: it does not always encode all the header contents, which saves space and leaves the text human-readable. The encoding is required only for the non-ASCII parts. The output analogous to the `iconv_mime_encode()` example above is:

```
Subject: Very long text containing special characters like
 =?UTF-8?B?xJvFocSNxZnFvsO9w6HDrcOpPD4/PSsqIHByb2R1Y2VzIHNldmVyYWwgZW5j?=
 =?UTF-8?B?b2RlZC13b3Jkcywgc3Bhbm5pbmcgbXVsdGlwbGUgbGluZXM=?=
```

Usage example of `mb_encode_mimeheader()`:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$encoded_subject = mb_encode_mimeheader("Subject: $subject", 'UTF-8');
$encoded_subject = substr($encoded_subject, strlen('Subject: '));
mail($to, $encoded_subject, $message, $headers);
```

This is an alternative to the snippet in TL;DR on top of this post. Instead of just reserving the space for `Subject:` , it actually puts it there and then removes it in order to be able to use it with the `mail()`’s stupid interface.

If you like mbstring functions better than the iconv ones, you might want to use [`mb_send_mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-send-mail.php). It uses [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) internally, but encodes subject and body of the message automatically. Again, [use with care](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-send-mail.php#95753).

## Headers other than Subject need different treatment

Note that you must not assume that encoding the whole contents of a header is OK for all headers that may contain non-ASCII characters. E.g. From, To, Cc, Bcc and Reply-To may contain names for the addresses they contain, but only the names may be encoded, not the addresses. The reason is that `<encoded-word>` token may replace just `<text>`, `<ctext>` and `<word>` tokens, and only under certain circumstances (see [§5 of RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-5)).

Encoding of non-ASCII text in other headers is a related but different question. *If you wish to know more about this topic, search. If you find no answer, ask another question and point me to it in the comments.*

Comment: This is the line that saved me : `iconv_mime_decode("=?CP1250?B?QWhvaiwgc3bsdGU=?=", 0, "UTF-8")`, +1 just for that line.

Answer (score 24):

[mb_encode_mimeheader()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php) for UTF-8 strings can be useful here, e.g.

```
$subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subjectText,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: I experienced strange effects when using mb-encode-mimeheader: The ``=?UTF-8?B?`` prefix was not added to the beginning of my subject string, but somewhere in the middle. So I reverted to building the encoded-word syntax manually as Gumbo has shown.

Comment: @Jpsy That’s fine. It suffices to just encode those words with non-ASCII characters or even just those characters alone. But you have to be aware that [intermediate spaces are getting collapsed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1294391/53114) which can lead to unexpected results.