# Sending Hebrew subject in php mail goes Klingon...?

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, email-headers

I'm trying to send email with hebrew content/subject like so:

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = "איזה יום יפה היום"; 
$message = 'ממש יום יפה';

$headers = 'From: email@email.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But what I get in the subject is more Klingon than modern Hebrew. The message itself comes out fine, it's just the subject that's all messed up.

What can I do? (I'm open to any hacks you got)

Comment: Somewhere along the way, your character encoding has become seriously messed up. As far as I know, ISO-8859-1 doesn't even have any Hebrew characters in it!

Comment: @David the message comes out ok, the problem is with the subject...

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389676/php-email-header-subject-encoding-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Content-Type* does only describe the message content but not the header. You need to apply the [*encoded-word* encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-2) on the *Subject* value. See [my answer on *PHP email header subject encoding problem*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389676/php-email-header-subject-encoding-problem/4389755#4389755) for further information.