# PHP unicode email

Tags: php

I want to send an email with a japanese characters in subject using PHP.
I can send by using jap characters in sender but when I use it in subject
email does not receive. 
How can I fix this problem. Please help.

Thanks,
Gyp

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389676/php-email-header-subject-encoding-problem

Comment: Have you tried `utf8_encode()`, or maybe `mail_utf8()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use PHPmailer library, I have never had problem with UTF8 characters while I use that. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: PHPMailer is good tip! Latest version [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/).

Answer (score 1):

[First result of google](http://robotlibrarian.billdueber.com/sending-unicode-email-headers-in-php/) (for "php unicode email")

Here's the code:

```
$headers['To'] = $to;
$headers['From'] = $from;
$headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
$headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = "8bit";
$b64subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=";
$headers['Subject'] = $b64subject;

$mail = Mail::factory('sendmail', array('host' => $host, 'port'=>$port));
$retval =  $mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: `=&` is outdated. Also, very soon, **this** will be the first result on google for "php unicode mail"

Comment: @Truth Haha you're right, but I was just pointing out that sometimes it's easier to just google it