# UTF-8 sender name in Zend_Mail?

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8, zend-mail

I am using Zend_Mail and want to customize the sender name.

I want the sender name to be **FooBar爱你Ryan** (where 'Ryan' gets replaced with the recipient name and 爱你 gets replaced with the translation for 'loves' in the language of the recipient, [just like CD Baby does](http://goo.gl/1Bwxq)).

I've tried [base64_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4389755/470749) and [mb_encode_mimeheader()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392582/470749) and other things like:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding("input_encoding", 'UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", 'UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", 'UTF-8'); 
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=' . 'UTF-8');
```

It generates this as the sender: `'=?UTF-8?B?RXh0cmFidXjniLHkvaByY3dhbHNoQGV4dHJhYnV4LmNvbQ==?= <email@example.com>'`

And then that appears in my Gmail as `(unknown sender)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code that actually sets the `From:` email header field?

Comment: $sendername='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($sendername).'?=';

Comment: Most recently I've been trying this: `$senderName = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($email->getFromName()) . "?=";
        $mail->clearFrom();
        $mail->setFrom($email->getFrom(), $senderName);` which happens to be what Arda suggested too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I had tried this earlier: when I hard code the Chinese string as the sender name (using utf8 characters), it works fine.  (I tested in Gmail only.)

So the path I'd been going down was mistaken.

I need to figure out why a dynamically-generated sender name consisting of utf8 characters doesn't work when a hard-coded Chinese string does.  But that seems to be a different question.

Comment: `$recipientCleaned = str_replace('@', $translator->translate(' at '), $recipient);` made it work.

Answer (score 2):

For me the only solution worked was the following:
As you'd set utf8 subject in a usual php sendmail case, you can make a utf8 noted base64 string like this:

```
$mail->addFrom($fromEmail, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($fromName).'?=');
```

With this solution every thing worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question and the answers are good - but ZendFramework advanced and the interfaces referenced became unfortunately obsolete.

So here is the same solution, but tested to work fine as of June/2017:

```
private static function ecvt($string)
{
    return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-2022-JP', 'UTF-8');
}
private static function hcvt($string)
{
    return "=?iso-2022-jp?B?" . base64_encode( self::ecvt($string) ) . "?=";
}
private function sendMail( )
{
    $mail = new Message();

    $content = 'Message body　日本語も';

    $mail->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP');

    $mail->setFrom('sender@acme.com', self::hcvt('Sender　日本語も') );
    $mail->addTo('receiver@acme.com', self::hcvt('Receiver 日本語も') );
    $mail->setSubject(self::hcvt('Some subject　日本語も'));

    $mail->setBody( self::ecvt($content) );
    $mail->setEncoding('ISO-2022-JP');

    // this is critical - it works around a bug in zendframework3 where
    // MIME encoding is botched in headers. By switching headers to ASCII,
    // I basically do the encoding myself.
    $mail->getHeaders()->setEncoding('ASCII');

    $this->mailTransport->send( $mail );
}
```

The basis for all this really is here - it is good to read so you know what is going on: RFC2047 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt